# I have a massive table that I need to optimize. I think I need to use indexes, but I was hoping for some more information about them

Tags: iphone, sqlite, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

So I have a large table that I query (select only) quite frequently. The table is around 12,000 rows long. Since the advent of iOS, the time that it is taking to run these select queries has gone up 4-5x.

I was told that I need to add an index to my table. The query that I am using looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM book_content WHERE book_id = ? AND chapter = ? ORDER BY verse ASC
```

How can I create an index for this table? Is it a command I just run once? What exactly is the index going to do? I didn't learn about these in school so they still seem like some sort of magic to me at this point, so I was hoping to get a little instruction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an index on book_id and chapter.  Without an index, a server would do a `table scan` and essentially load the entire table into memory to do its search.  Do a quick search on the `CREATE INDEX` command for the RDBMS that you are using.  You create the index once and every time you do an `INSERT` or `DELETE` or `UPDATE`, the server will update the index automatically.  An index can be `UNIQUE` and it can be on multiple fields (in your case, book_id and chapter).  If you make it `UNIQUE`, the database will not allow you to insert a second row with the same key (in this case, book_id and chapter).  On most servers, having one index on two fields is different from having two individual indexes on single fields each.

A Mysql example would be:

```
CREATE INDEX id_chapter_idx ON book_content (book_id,chapter);
```

If you want only one record for each book_id, chapter combination, use this command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_chapter_idx ON book_content (book_id,chapter);
```

A `PRIMARY INDEX` is a special index that is `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.  Each table can only have one primary index.  In fact, each table should have one primary index to ensure table integrity, especially during joins.

Comment: My preferred method of all my tables is to first create a field "ID" which is the primary key and has identity specification on. This means that it always creates a unique number on every new record automatically. With identity on, you cannot set the ID. But with identity off with the primary key on, then the ID field will allow you to set the ID, just you cannot duplicate it or leave it NULL. I know that ID field will have its own automatic index, and if I have another field which is commonly used, then I create one on that field. No more than 3 or so fields though.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to think of indexes as "magic".

An index on an SQL table is much like the index in a printed book - it lets you find what you're looking for without reading the entire book cover-to-cover.

For example, say you have a cookbook, and you're looking for recipes that involve chicken. The index in the back of the book might say something like:

```
chicken: 30,34,72,84
```

letting you know that you will find chicken recipes on those 4 pages. It's much faster to find this information in the index than by reading through the whole book, because the index is shorter, and (more importantly) it's in alphabetical order, so you can quickly find the right place in the index.

So, in general you want to create indexes on columns that you will regularly need to query (book_id and chapter, in your example).

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a column as primary key automatically generates an index on that column. In your case for using more often select an index is ideal, because they improve time of selection queries and degrade the time of insertion. So you can create the indexes you think you need without worrying about the performance

Comment: +1 for mentioning the auto-creation of the primary key's index, but I still disagree with 'creating the indexes you think you need without worrying about the performance' because it highly depends on the usage of those indexes. If an index is made for 1 query, then other queries on that table which don't need that index will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are a very sensitive subject. If you consider using them, you need to be very careful how many you make. The primary key, or id, of each table should have a clustered index. All the rest, it depends on how you plan to use them. I'm very fuzzy in the subject of indexes, and have actually never worked with them, but from a seminar I just watched actually yesterday, you don't want too many indexes - because they can actually slow things down when you don't need to use them.

Let's say you put an index on 5 out of 8 fields on a table. Each index is designated for a particular query somewhere in your software. Well, when 1 query is run, it uses that 1 index, and doesn't need the other 4. So that's unneeded weight on this 1 query. If you need an index, be sure that this is an index which could be useful in many places, not just 1 place.

Comment: PS I know that's not necessarily answering your question, but it is very important information to know if you want to implement indexes.

Comment: A good index will also have many values (this is called 'selectivity'); if we're talking about a personnel database table, then there's no point in indexing the person's gender because there are only two values. A good index has low selectivity.

Comment: That is a good point, Y/N or 1/0 or True/False fields, or fields where there are less than 5 possible values, are not a good place to put an index. With a table of 12,000 records of book chapters, the "BookID" field would be a great place to put an index.